# Остановка горутины

Tags: golang

Всем привет. Стоит задача: Реализовать остановку горутины. Я делаю так:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
)

func Work(data []int, lendata int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    quite := make(chan bool)
    for i := 0; i < lendata; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            log.Println(data[i])
            wg.Done()
            select {
            case <-quite:
                return
            default:
            }
        }(i)
    }
    log.Println("EXIT")
    quite <- true
}

func main() {
    slc := make([]int, 0)
    slc = append(slc, 12, 32, 65, 34, 54, 87)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    lendata := len(slc)
    wg.Add(lendata)
    Work(slc, lendata, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

В выводе я получаю

```
2022/05/14 14:21:18 EXIT
2022/05/14 14:21:18 32
2022/05/14 14:21:18 12
2022/05/14 14:21:18 34
2022/05/14 14:21:18 65
2022/05/14 14:21:18 54
2022/05/14 14:21:18 87
//порядок естесстенно разный у чисел
```

В моем понимании, после первого прохода цикла горутина должна остановиться и остальные проходы не выполниться или я не прав?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
)
//wg.Done() вызывает deadlock и панику, куда бы я его не поставил
//поэтому в этом примере я его не ставлю, так как возможно проблема уже здесь
func Work(data []int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    quite := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for _, item := range data {
            log.Println(item)
            select {
            case <-quite:
                return
            default:
            }
        }
    }()
    log.Println("EXIT")
    quite <- true
}

func makechan() {
    slc := make([]int, 0)
    slc = append(slc, 12, 32, 65, 34, 54, 87)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    lendata := len(slc)
    wg.Add(lendata)
    Work(slc, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Ожидаемое поведение: после первого прохода цикла горутина останавливается не вызывая панику по deadlock. Моя догадка6 не нужно использовать waitgroup

Я сделал [такой](https://go.dev/play/p/EnBoDcKYeeH) пример, но он зацикливается на пустом default в Work()

Comment: В горутинах нет циклов, а `wg.Done()` вызывается не при выходе.

Comment: @user7860670 имеете ввиду что цикл нужно засунуть  внутрь горутины, в wg.Done() на выходе из цикла вызывать?

Comment: @user7860670 если я делаю цикл внутри горутины, то горутина то останавливается, но куда бы я не ставил Done получаю deadlock и панику

Comment: wg.Done() должно быть перед выходом, *"если я делаю цикл внутри горутины, то горутина то останавливается, но куда бы я не ставил Done получаю deadlock и панику"* - в вопросе ничего этого нет, как нет и ожидаемого поведения

Comment: @user7860670 я добавил вариант в котором цикл внутри горутины.

Comment: знаю, что не важно, но у Вас канал назван `quite`, что переводится, как `тихий`; вероятно, вы хотели написать `quit`)

Comment: @Quester он имел в виду заключить `select` в "вечный" цикл for.
на тему `wg.Done()`: лучше его поместить в `defer` в вызове горутины (в первом варианте), чтобы оно гарантированно выполнилось

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых: вам не подойдет канал для закрытия НЕСКОЛЬКИХ горутин с 1 сообщением, тк горутин больше чем 1 (разве чт опроверять не читает ли горутина закрытый канал).
Другие горутины слушают канал, но от туда ничего не придет — первая горутина вычитала сообщение из канала (то есть забрала его), а в канал никто ничего больше не шлет и др горутины не дождутся сообщения

Во-вторых: Если используете select/case только для прослушка сигнала о закрытии, то нужно обернуть в бесконечный цикл for, чтобы она не была припаркована, тк выполнится default у вас и все — дальше выполняться нечему. А если сейчас for добавить и wg.Done() перед return —  программа не завершится (тк горутины не завершатся, тк завершится только первая из них (прошлый пункт))

В-третьих (итог): лучше использовать контекст, вот ответ на ваш вопрос от меня с примером [Потoкобезопасное завершение программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1409038/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82o%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b/1409126#1409126)

Comment: я что-то не вьезжаю. Это же дргуая абсолютно задача. Не вьезжаю где в приведенном примере остановка горутины

Comment: @Quester в функции Worker на шаге case <-ctx.Done():

Comment: Я добавил пример в вопрос. Там зацикливается на default. Не понимаю, как оно завершиться должно без моего вмешательства

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы горутина вывела одно число из массива и остановилась. Как я это вижу: вывод значений запускается в одной горутине, горутина выводит первое попавшееся значение(из слайса) и останавливается и остальные значения не выводятся

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/oWNlaA8EUqY вот работающий пример: там main чистая (ждет или ввод от юзера отмены или результат), Do() создает горутины и одновременно пишет в канал, горутина или ждет своего значения или остановку из вне. Горутины прибиваются корректно (закроется если захватит одно значение из канала или если сигнал остановки придет снаружи)

Comment: Я в принципе понимаю, что происходит в коде, но мне требуется дргуое поведение. Мне нужно чтобы Пусть горутина и одна но она внутри себя показывала значния из слайса НО после вывода первого значния останавливалась и не выводила следующие.

Comment: Да, это и реализовано… как только горутина получит одно значение — выполнит и завершится… если не успеет прочитать (прилетит сигнал о завершении) — тоже завершится… там после лога о выполнении идёт ретерн